# Wifi at home(no modem) but my bluray player and PS2 have ethernet port how do i connect?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, blu-ray, wired-networking, playstation

i have Wifi at home(using HTC hotspot) no other modem
but my phillips bluray player and sony PS2 have ethernet port how do i connect?

Please advice

Comment: Typical way is to have a computer connect to your phone (the "HTC hotspot") using Wi-Fi or a USB cable.  Then have other devices like BluRay player connect via Ethernet to the computer.  Other devices may or may not work well.  Providing model numbers may be essential to being able to provide certain answers, like whether your Blu-Ray player is compatible with a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bridge to go from wired ethernet to wireless ethernet. Here is the process:

- Connect an ethernet cable between the bridge and the PS2
- Assign the bridge an IP address using DHCP or Static IP from your router
- Use that IP address as the gateway address of the PS2
- Assign an IP address to the PS2 using DHCP or Static IP from the bridge

**References**

- [Linksys WirelessG Game Adapter](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-product?pid=01t80000003KYsYAAW)
- [Linksys WGA54G Manual](http://www.ps2netdrivers.net/setup/linksys.wga54g/)

Answer (score 0):

Some wifi extenders have ethernet ports, so they act as a bridge from wired to wireless. I personally use a Netgear WN2000RPTv2 for this very purpose.

Comment: The op uses a phone as a router and as far as I am aware, phones Do NOT have ethernet  ports...

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have a WN2000RPTv2 that connects to wifi (phone, in this case), and use the ethernet ports on the WN2000RPTv2 for devices that can not connect to wifi.